# Azure Web Apps restriction

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I have three Azure Web Apps. Two Web Apps must have internet access and be publicly accessible. The third should be closed behind restrictions from the outside world and communicate only with these two Web Apps. I tried with restrictions but it didn't work for me. Could you tell me how to set up this interaction correctly from the point of view of the Azure architecture. Thanks.

Comment: "I tried with restrictions" Please edit you question describing what you did

Answer (score 0):

1-You can setup network rules around allowed IP address for Web App 3:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions